# How to join Google meet automatically when the host starts the meet?

Tags: class, openmeetings, google-meet

I want to know if there is any way we can join the meeting automatically when the host starts the meet. In meet links like shown below, we have to reload the page continuously until the host doesn't start the meet.

[Here is the page when the host hasn't started the meet, we have to continuously reload it until the host comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIKuS.png)

[This is the page when the host starts the meet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebmHD.png)

Comment: Have you checked this with google/ meet support? This is how it works with most other apps

Comment: No. There is nothing helpful there.

Comment: Google meet is incompatible with Apache OpenMeetings, I believe you should remove `openmeetings` tag

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Chromium based browser(eg Brave, Vivaldi, Google Chrome), use [Google Meet Enhancement Suite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-meet-enhancement-s/ljojmlmdapmnibgflmmminacbjebjpno) in combination with an autorefresh extension.
There are some problems with it- you can get a page where it won't automatically reload, but works fine otherwise.